# Posts on archive page of custom post type: how to add default featured image?

Tags: php, wordpress

Posts on archive page of custom post type: how to add default featured image?

So, there a lot of images on these post types. Basically I want to add a featured image by default to be shown on the archive page of this custom post type per post.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am  using acf plugin and i added featured image for custom post type with custom field like this

```html
function acf_set_featured_image( $value, $post_id, $field  ){
    
    if($value != ''){
        //Add the value which is the image ID to the _thumbnail_id meta data for the current post
        add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $value);
    }
 
    return $value;
}

// acf/update_value/name={$field_name} - filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=client_logo_here', 'acf_set_featured_image', 10, 3);
```

Comment: And without this plugin?

Comment: you can use save_post hook to save _thumbnail_id